# Symfony-2 - Localização dos assets

Tags: php, symfony-2

Minha aplicação está sendo feita usando Symfony-2, e essa aplicação eu não vou distribuí-la.

O ideal é eu manter meus assets em `AppBundle/Resources/public/` e ficar aplicando `console assets:install`, ou o ideal é eu deixar meus assets direto em `web/bundles/app/` para não precisar ficar aplicando `console assets:install`? (Lembrando que não vou distribuir essa aplicação)

Como eu não vou distribuir essa aplicação, quais vantagens e desvantagens eu tenho nesses dois locais diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois são validos, mas como você não vai distribuir a aplicação é mais comodo pra você deixar no `/web` diretamente. Caso você deixe na pasta `AppBundle/Resources/Public/...` vai precisar rodar o comando `app/console assets:install --symlink --relative` sempre que alterar algo no arquivo, o que no seu caso é desnecessário.

As boas praticas do symfony diz que é para colocar na pasta /web
[Symfony best pratices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)